# Issues with php-mongodb extension 1.4.1 and DoctrineMongoDBBundle

Tags: symfony, composer-php

I am unable to install the DoctrineMongoDBundle with php-mongodb extension 1.4.1 from Composer in Ubuntu 12.04. According to the error it requires a version lesser than 1.4.1. Following is the error. I have enabled the 1.4.1 extension but it says it is missing.

doctrine/mongodb 1.0.2 requires ext-mongo >=1.2.12,<1.4-dev -> the requested PHP extension mongo is missing from your system.

Even I tried to add 1.2.12 no success so far.

Note: I had asked a similar question before and solutions worked on Windows. Any idea about this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue by enabling the php-mongodb extensions in both php.ini files.
(/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini and /etc/php5/cli/php.ini.